# How to change android project requirements for Google API?

Tags: android

I changed 
`project> Android > Google Api 8` and
`project > Run/Debug settings > Target tab > Gooogle api 8 2.2`
And I am still getting:

```
[2011-12-08 13:42:23 - geoplanner] ERROR: Application requires API version 14. Device API version is 8 (Android 2.2).
[2011-12-08 13:42:23 - geoplanner] Launch canceled!
```

What should I change to run my project properly?

Comment: Tell us about your "permissions" and the features you use. Maybe your are using something that is only available from version 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API versions are defined here:
http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

You should:
1) Remove features that require API 14 if there are any
2) In the manifest file, change the line that says(and put a lower number):

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you check the contents of the manifest file too: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html